# Grails - Cannot install any plugin from grailsCentral

Tags: grails, dependency-management, grails-plugin

I'm trying to install these plugins:

- Spring Security Core
- Spring Security UI
- Jasper

But I can't install any of them.

The following error is produced when adding `compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0'` line to `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java" -Dgrails.home=C:\grails-2.4.5 -Dbase.dir=C:\Users\Usuario\IdeaProjects\SCHLUMBERGER_SURENCO\sfceSchlumbergerSurenco "-Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\grails-2.4.5/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\grails-2.4.5\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-2.3.11.jar;C:\grails-2.4.5\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.4.5.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:\grails-2.4.5/conf/groovy-starter.conf "idea-print-project-settings -plain-output"|Loading Grails 2.4.5
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:jar:2.0.0 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:jar:2.0.0 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:jar:2.0.0 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:jar:2.0.0 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

The following error is produced when adding `compile 'org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.11.0'` line to `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:jasper:jar:1.11.0 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:jasper:jar:1.11.0 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:jasper:jar:1.11.0 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:jasper:jar:1.11.0 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

Environment:

- Grails 2.4.5
- Java 1.8.0_101
- IntelliJ IDEA 15.0
- Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the errors are for jars that cannot be found, it looks like you're putting plugin dependency statements in the `dependencies` block, but they should be in the `plugins` block. You can also omit "org.grails.plugins" when specifying plugins since that's the default:

```
plugins {
   compile ':spring-security-core:2.0.0'
   compile ':spring-security-ui:1.0-RC3'
   compile ':jasper:1.11.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. BTW, how do I know when to put the reference in `dependencies` or `plugins`?

Comment: Plugins go in the `plugins` block, jars go in the `dependencies` block. Note though that in Grails 3 plugins are compiled and deployed as jars, so everything is a jar dependency.